# boilerplate code for C++

Tags: firebase

I want to rewrite  my old .net app based on FirebAse with the new C++ SDK, I have managed to link and compile the libraries in my VS2015 environment, but now have no idea about how to use them.
The firebase quick start here:
https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-cpp/tree/master/auth/testapp/src/desktop
doesn't really show anything.
Am I looking in the wrong place?

Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

Firebase C++ only provides stub libraries as a convenience for desktop at the moment so while you'll be able to link the libraries they won't actually do anything.  We have a desktop implementation of our light platform abstraction layer for internal testing only - notice we don't ship desktop MSVC or Xcode projects.

See the readme.md in the Firebase SDK zip file for more information.